# Can I achieve full width of table on mobile screen using Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, mobile, vuetify.js, responsive

Can I achieve having table 'zoomed-out' on small screen using Vue2 and Vuetify?

I have a task where table needs to remain being full width on mobile screen where it can be zoomed in. To basically achieve img-like behavior.

I basically need to achieve this second screen from this image, but using `v-data-table` .
[image]

Even though "they both equally suck", I need the second solution.

Is there any Vuetify specific solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In vuetify you can use `v-data-table` and use prop `mobile-breakpoint="0"`

```
 <v-data-table
     ...
      mobile-breakpoint="0"
    ...         
    ></v-data-table>
```

Comment: I know this one but it just keeps table same size still..

Comment: according to github issues, using v-data-table you can not achieve 'second solution' you can try some custom css.
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6399